# How to generate strings in a for loop following a pattern?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I want to get an output like this

```
name1
name2
name3
name4
```

to n number of names with suffix as the range of x.
How to use for loop to generate this kind of output?

Answer (score 0):

For printing variables within strings, you can use [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) since Python 3.6, as in the following example:

### Code:

```
for i in range(1, 5):
    print(f"name{i}")
```

### Output:

```
name1
name2
name3
name4
```